# MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE with CRC32 and CONCAT

Tags: mysql, concatenation, load-data-infile, crc32

I import a CSV with load data infile. one field should contain the crc32 value as hash of 3 others.

eg. LOAD DATA INFILE.... (field1,field2,field3,crc) set crc = crc32(concat(field1,field2,field3))

This workds so far but when comparing i can see that often fields contains different CRC32 values even theere is no change at all ? Why ? Where is my fail ?

Comment: It still wont work. I tried the following (field type hash is char32 unsigned)      My update syntax of both tables "update export1 set crc = md5(concat(column1,',',column2,',',column3))" and same in other table but md5 is different as well when using crc32 ...

Answer (score 0):

Yu can use a virtual Column that calculate direct your CRC32. Dont forget the colon between the Columns.

Sample

```
 a    b    c    crc32
123   4    5
1234  NULL 5
```

are the same crc32 if not use colon between it

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
     a INT NOT NULL,
     b VARCHAR(32),
     c INT AS (a mod 10) VIRTUAL,
     d VARCHAR(5) AS (CRC32(concat(a,',',b,',',c,)) PERSISTENT);
```